# How to strip white spaces in Python without using a string method?

Tags: python, removing-whitespace

I am fairly new to programming and have been learning some of the material through HackerRank. However, there is this one objective or challenge that I am currently stuck on. I've tried several things but still cannot figure out what exactly I am doing wrong.

Objective: Read N and output the numbers between 0 and N *without any white spaces or using a string method.*

```
N = int(input())
listofnum = []

for i in range(1, N +1):
    listofnum.append(i)
print (*(listofnum))
```

Output :

```
1 2 3
```

Comment: why don't you print numbers inside loop. You don't need to create array for that. Just use `print(i, end="")`

Comment: @EvgenyKuzmovich: Thank you so much! I am not familiar with the end='' but will definitely read up on that now.

Comment: @EvgenyKuzmovich: Could you add your answer as a comment so that I can mark it and others could reference it later?

Comment: Sure. Already done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can print numbers inside the loop. Just use `end` keyword in `print`:

```
print(i, end="")
```

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre obviously you can't print anything without using strings somehow. I think the task says that you can't use string methods and I didn't.

Comment: I think those challenges are kind of funny but stupid. The most efficient way is just with `join`. and see my answer (with the help of tdelaney): no strings attached :)

Answer (score 2):

Without using any string method, just using integer division and `list` to reverse the digits, print them using `sys.stdout.write`:

```
import sys
N = int(input())

for i in range(1,N+1):
    l=[]
    while(i):
        l.append(i%10)
        i //= 10
    for c in reversed(l):
        sys.stdout.write(chr(c+48))
```

Or as tdelaney suggested, an even more hard-code method:

```
import os,sys,struct

N = int(input())

for i in range(1,N+1):
    l=[]
    while(i):
        l.append(i%10)
        i //= 10
    for c in reversed(l):
        os.write(sys.stdout.fileno(), struct.pack('b', c+48))
```

All of this is great fun, but the best way, though, would be with a one-liner with a generator comprehension to do that, using `str.join()` and `str` construction:

```
"".join(str(x) for x in range(1,N+1))
```

Each number is converted into string, and the `join` operator just concatenates all the digits with empty separator.

Comment: `"".join` is a builtin string **method**. Chris and Alex just pointed out to me. Its not a operator.

Comment: I edited my answer. You won't see the `str` word in it.

Comment: Nice alternate solution, but I was thinking something more like this would be eaiser: `print(*[el for el in range(0, int(input())+1)], sep="")`

Comment: Great answer! But does `chr` still count as a string method? It calls `str.__init__`. `struct.pack('b', c+48)` may be called for here.

Comment: @tdelaney: you have to convert to char at some point. There's no distinction between `char` and `string` in python unlike C. The solution does the "heavy lifting" just like if you don't have access to integer to string conversion.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre `os.write(sys.stdout.fileno(), struct.pack('b', 0x30))` no strings!

Comment: @tdelaney that's really low-level. Even pyscripter cannot display it :) but on command line it works.

Comment: Sorry to pounce on your answer but I was seeing how far I could push it and had your solution with that small tweak. Well, I was trying to write some  machine code and jump to it, but that didn't work at all well. Time to fire up `cython`! Or maybe step away from the computer for a bit...

Comment: no problem! your knowledge of the low-level python stuff is excellent. I learnt a few things there...

Answer (score 2):

```
N = int(input())
answer = ''
for i in range(1, N + 1):
    answer += str(i)
print(answer)
```

This is the closest I can think of to 'not using any string methods', although technically it is using `str.__new__/__init__/__add__` in the background or some equivalent. I certainly think it fits the requirements of the question better than using `''.join`.

Comment: Why not use `repr` instead of `str`?  `str` looks too much like "using a string method" to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `print()`'s `sep` argument to "bind" each number together from a list comprehension:

```
>>> print(*[el for el in range(0, int(input())+1)], sep="")
10
012345678910
>>>
```

Comment: `join` is a string method, no?

Comment: @leaf not sure what you mean, if you inspect it you get `<built-in method join of str object at 0x10df76ab0>`.

Answer (score 0):

Try ''.join([str(i) for i in range(N)])

Comment: `"".join` is a builtin string **method**. Chris and Alex just pointed out to me.

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish this is to append the numbers to a blank string.

```
out = ''
for i in range(N):
    out += str(i)
print(out)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do a simple math to do this. What they expect to do is multiply each of your list elements by powers of ten and add them up on each other. As an example let's say you have an array;
a = [2,3,5]
and you need to output;
235

Then you multiply each of loop elements starting from right to left by 10^0, 10^1 and 10^2. You this code after you make the string list.

```
a = map(int,a)
for i in range(len(a)):
    sum += (10**i)*a[-i]
print sum
```

You are done!

Comment: your code doesn't run as-is. Please provide a working snippet.

Comment: Two things: first, there are much more efficient ways (e.g. `total = 0; for i in range(n):; total = total * 10 + i`).  Second, we weren't given a limit on what `N` could be.  This idea works for digits, but what if we need to output the numbers 0 to 11?  The algorithm won't generate 01234567891011.